# Is there any function in GSHEET to make dropdown list where choosing a particular value in one cell will return a predestined value in different cell

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

List looks like this -

| Fruits | Price |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | ₹ 100/kg |
| Banana | ₹ 40/kg |
| Grapes | ₹ 30/kg |
| Pineapple | ₹ 40/kg |
| Melon | ₹ 35/kg |

Looking for a method or formula to make dropdown list in the Gsheet - where if on choosing "Apple" it should automatically take apple's price value in another cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Vlookup` will do or you are looking for something else?:

```
=VLOOKUP(D25,A26:B30,2,false)
```

[image]